# Python mysql.connector error

Tags: python, mysql

I am facing an error while executing a python script.

Checked with directly using the users and password.
Checked with saved the users and pass in variables too.

Script:

```
import mysql.connector,sys
try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect (host='localhost', user = 'user', password = 'user@543', port= 3306)
except mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError, e:
    print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"Error %s" % (e)
    sys.exit(1)
except mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError, e1:
    print time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"Error %s" % (e1)
    sys.exit(1)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select version()")
    result_set = cursor.fetchall()
    print result_set
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect (host='localhost', user = 'user', password = 'user@543', port= 3306)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'connector'
```

Comment: do you use `mysql` as a variable name anywhere above the code fragment you posted?

Comment: No i didn't used the variable

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo.  There's a space between `connect` and the argument list. Change the line to:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost', user='user', password='user@543', port=3306
)
```